# Determine whether the following function is (a) injective and (b) surjective

Tags: real-analysis, functions

the function is as follows: $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x) =$ the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.

here is what I have for the proof of injective:

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ that is,

the least integer $\geq x =$ the least integer $\geq y$

I thought that this pretty obviously implied that $x=y$.

I am unsure as to how to begin the proof of surjective.

Can someone help?

Comment: "I thought that this pretty obviously implied that $x = y$." Why?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese because it is implying that the least integers have to be the same? or am I wrong?

Comment: Do you really mean "the least integer greater than or equal to **zero**"? That sounds like a function identically equal to $0$...

Comment: I believe he means "the least integer greater than or equal to $x$".

Comment: The least integers (namely $f(x)$ and $f(y)$) have to be the same, yes. But why does that imply $x$ and $y$ are the same?

Comment: well because for example, take x=5 and y=4, then f(x) = 5 and then f(y) = 4? and then f(x) $ \neq$ f(y)..  i think I am confusing myself

Comment: Hint: what is $f(1.1)$ and $f(1.3)$. What does this imply about the injectivity of $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function in question is known as the ceiling function $f(x)=\lceil x \rceil$.

To show that it is not injective, a single counterexample will do:

$$f(1.1)=f(1.3)=2\text{ and }1.1\ne1.3$$

To show that the function is surjective take $f(x)=n$ for an arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we can take $x_0=n$ (or $x_0=n-\frac{1}{2}$) so that $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x_0)=n$.

Comment: You beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 2):

The function you want to study is sometimes called the "ceiling function" with the notation $x\mapsto\lceil x\rceil$. It basically rounds up a real number to the closest integer greater than it. Observe that any realy number can be written as a sum of an integer and a (possibly non-repeating) fraction. As a side note, this representation may not be unique (e.g. $0.999...9...=1.000...0...$). In this sense, the function does the following:

$$a_na_{n-1}...a_{1}.a_{-1}a_{-2}...a_{-n}...\mapsto a_na_{n-1}...a_{1}.$$

For instance $f(\pi)=4, f(1/2)=1, f(5)=5, f(0.999...9...)=1$. This last example also hints at that we can disregard the multiple representation issue for the time being.

Now consider $\lceil\cdot\rceil:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Note that the target space is not shrunk to integers "externally": by the definition of $\lceil\cdot\rceil$, $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ can not take a non-integer value.

If you draw the graph of $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ I believe it will be very easy to find a counterexample showing that $f$ is not injective. In fact, we have that

$$ (\star)\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}:f(]n-1,n])=n \mbox{ (why?)}.$$

For surjectivity, you have to prove the following (generic) statement:

$$\forall t\in \mathbb{Z},\exists s\in \mathbb{R}:f(s)=t.$$

This is just a formal way of saying that any integer is attained by $f$.

As a final remark, note that it suffices to prove $(\star)$ for both the non-injectivity and surjectivity.